# Files read from source folder not being recognized as files or directories

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh, gnu

Here is my code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "USAGE: `basename $0` ./dir_from ./dir_to"
    exit -1
fi

source=$1
destination=$2

if [ ! -d $source ]
then
    echo "ERROR: Source directory doesn't exist."
    exit -1
fi

if [ ! -d $destination ]
then
    mkdir $destination
fi

allFiles=`ls $source`
total=0

for file in $allFiles
do
    echo $file
    fileName="${file%%.*}"
    extension="${file##*.}"
    size=`ls -l $file | awk '{print $6}'`
    echo $size

    if [ -f $file ] && [ "$extension" == "txt" ] && [[ "$fileName" =~ "^[a-z]*$" ]]
    then
        mv "${source}/${file}" "${destination}/${file}.moved_txt"
    fi
done
```

Here are the contents of the `source` folder:

```sh
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 191128 domain users 32 May 22 15:01 afile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 191128 domain users  0 May 22 15:01 pleaseeeee.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 191128 domain users 17 May 22 15:01 pls.txt
```

The problem I'm facing is the test to see if a file is actually a file, `[ -f $file ]`, doesn't work. It says that they are not files.

Everything except that condition works. Yes, the correct folder is in the `source` variable and yes, the `for` loop spits out all the files from the folder.

If I try the test `-d` to see if they are directories, that also fails. Only when I negate `-f` do they appear, which is really strange.

They clearly are files (indicated by the `-`). I created them with the command `touch`, and I have also tried creating them with the command `nano` and typing something. I have also tried creating the files from the home directory and moving them to my source folder `from` to see if that would change anything and it didn't. Now here is something interesting: if the files are in the same directory as the script, it works (they are recognized as files).

Any ideas and comments are appreciated.

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation.

Comment: `if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then echo "USAGE: $(basename $0) ./dir_from ./dir_to"; exit -1; fi` is *not* best practice.  (But it's so damn common that it needs to be addressed!).  If you exit non-zero, then your program failed.  But you didn't print an error message.  If you print a usage statement, you should exit 0.  Make a choice.  Either print an error message (make it brief) to stderr and exit non-zero, or print a usage statement to stdout and exit 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question because I figured out my mistake. I don't know if this is allowed on stack-overflow but I would appreciate if this question stayed here if anyone else faces the same mistake.

In my variable `allFiles` I only have the file names. I need to concatenate the actual path to the files.

```
if [ -f "$source/$file" ]
```

Comment: You are even encouraged to _accept_ your answer.